# Gstreamer first steps - "Undefined symbols..." error

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation, gstreamer

Probably a noob question but I can't find an answer to this. I've downloaded and installed Gstreamer for Mac from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-init.html

I copied the code for example 4.1, to initialize GStreamer, from
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-init.html into a file called eg41.c
and used the terminal command `gcc eg41.c -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers`
. The output was:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_gst_init", referenced from: _main in eg41-9814a5.o
>   "_gst_version", referenced from: _main in eg41-9814a5.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any ideas?

Comment: You're not linking with the GStreamer library, only adding the header path to the include directories. Also, you should probably be using `pkg-config` instead of hardcoding the paths anyway.

Comment: Daniel, Thanks! I "git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/pkg-config" and that seemed to work. But then "gcc eg41.c -o eg41 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10'" threw an "clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config..." error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I found a solution - it might not be the best way but "gcc eg41.c -framework GStreamer -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers -o eg41" works!